# INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE BSOD after cloning a drive, but only when the old drive is still connected

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bsod, clone

I've used Clonezilla to copy my Windows installation to a new drive. I have done a disk-to-disk copy, from the old SATA SSD to the new NVMe SSD. Upon removing the old drive, the new drive boots just fine and everything works. However, when I plug in the old drive and try to boot the new one, it will fail to boot with an INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE, before the old drive is picked up and boots just fine.

With the old hard drive unplugged and plugged in on separate attempts, just to be sure, I have tried:

1. Using a Windows installation media to run Windows Startup Repair. It couldn't find any issues.
2. Using the same Windows installation media, `Bootrec /fixMbr` followed by `Bootrec /fixBoot`. I have also tried `Bootrec /RebuildBcd` on a separate attempt. No combination has returned any good results.

So my question is, what can I do so that Windows will boot from the new drive while the old one is still plugged in?

Comment: This probably has to do with two drives with identical EFI partitions. This is evident by the fact the system boots to the old drive while plugged in, at least thats what it appears your saying if not you should clarify your question by editing it

Comment: @Ramhound What you described about the system automatically booting the old drive after the new one fails is correct. I've edited my question a bit for clarity. I think I remember finding a similar question that described a way to reset or modify the EFI partition or something similar, but I can't find it now. Seems to me though that there wouldn't be any problem with just wiping the old drive and moving on with my life instead.

Comment: @Ramhound I just realized that both disks are MBR. Isn't an EFI partition solely a UEFI thing?

Comment: You installed Windows 10 on a NVMe device in Legacy Mode? That’s one issue…are you positive you are actually booting from the new device?

Comment: @Ramhound The old drive is physically removed when I load from the new one, so yes, I'm absolutely positive it's booting the new one. I double checked and it is in legacy mode while doing so.

Comment: For anyone reading, I just eventually gave up and let the new install do its thing. If the partitions are genuinely identically identified, then just removing the old drive shouldn't be a problem. I'll leave another comment in the future, if it ever breaks, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author no longer has the described problem

Comment: The problem is still a problem, I never got a solution, I simply decided not to fix it and I am still genuinely curious HOW I would fix this problem. I still have the second drive sitting here, identical, still causing problems, just disconnected. There's likely a duplicate question somewhere centered around MBR and I'd be very happy to see that.

Comment: wipe old drive.

Answer (score 0):

I did the exact same procedure you explained with Clonezilla and got same result as you.

I fixed it by changing boot mode for the PCI devices from UEFI to legacy, this allows the PC to boot from the new SSD, but the old disk has to be disconnected.

Before I can use both disks I removed the new one, connected the old disk and formated it also using Clonezilla, so it doesn't cause conflicts.

[image]